# avoid hook for particular view page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I want to avoid hook for particular view page in codeigniter.

I am using HTML Minify concept using display_override hook. But at the time of pdf creation I am facing problems.

I want some solution on this. Please suggest me the way to avoid hook for particular view.

Thank you

Comment: Guys  Please help me out this

Comment: can you put some code with more explanation?

Comment: $hook['display_override'][] = array(
    'class' => '',
    'function' => 'compress',
    'filename' => 'compress.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);     This is my hook...... it calls every time when I load view . But I want to avoid this for particular view

Comment: Write special code, for example, meta tag. If it is absent or present do needed transformation. You may remove it in hook to don't sent  to browser

Comment: Hello splash58 , I am new in this... can you please explain in details...please